# Set mouse over image from upper left to lower right

Tags: jquery, onmouseover

```
<script type=text/javascript src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#image").mousemove(function(e) {
    $("#pop-up").fadeIn(0);
    $("#pop-up").offset({
        top: e.pageY - $("#pop-up").outerHeight()+2,
        left: e.pageX - ($("#pop-up").outerWidth()+18)
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $("#pop-up").fadeOut(250);
                     });
                                             });
</script>
```

I am not sure what to set the offset to, right now the image is on the upper left of the mouse pointer, I want to move it to the lower right.  Or should I be using another option in jquery (hover()?)

HTML code:

```
             <div>
             <span id="pop-up" style="position: absolute; display:none;">
             <img src="../images/webp01.png" id="re"></span>
             <div id="image" style="width:208px; height:318px; margin-left: 150px;"><a href="#">
             <img src="../images/webp02.png" border=none /></a></div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8GVFC/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#image").mousemove(function(e) {
    $("#pop-up").fadeIn(0);
    $("#pop-up").offset({
        top: e.pageY+20, // Approximate mouse height: 20
        left: e.pageX+15 // Approximate mouse width: 15
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $("#pop-up").fadeOut(250);
                     });                                             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GVFC/) out

***JavaScript***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#image").mousemove(function(e) {
    $("#pop-up").fadeIn(0);
    $("#pop-up").offset({
        top: e.pageY - $("#myImage").outerHeight(),
        left: e.pageX  - ($("#myImage").outerWidth())
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $("#pop-up").fadeOut(250);
                     });                                             
});
```

***HTML***

```
<div >
    <span id="pop-up" style="position: absolute; display:none;">
        <img id='myImage' width=30  height=100 src="../images/webp01.png" id="re">
    </span>
    <div id="image" style="border:solid 1px black; width:208px; height:318px; margin-left: 150px;"><a href="#">
        <img src="../images/webp02.png" border=none /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```